# How to Implement Encapsulation In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to Javascript and I was reading the docs and,

According to MDN Docs :-

> Keeping an **object's internal state private**, and generally making a
> clear division between its public interface and its private internal
> state, is called encapsulation.

They have not mentioned

How to keep an Object's Internal State Private ?

Also its mentioned further that,

> In languages that don't enforce access like this, programmers use
> naming conventions, such as starting the name with an underscore, to
> indicate that the property should be considered private.

So what does this line mean

> starting the name with an underscore, to indicate that the property
> should be considered private.

Does this mean if I put `_` before a property name it would **become** private, isn't there a difference between becoming private and making private. Does putting an underscore tells Javascript explicitly that this property is private ?

Also they have not provided any concrete code to explain that part I could only find the pseudocode

```
class Student : extends Person
    properties
       year
    constructor
        Student(name, year)
    methods
       introduceSelf()
       canStudyArchery() { return this.year > 1 }
```

I googled [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348504/javascript-encapsulation) and found that closures are used to implement encapsulation behaviour, but the MDN Docs have not stated this anywhere [Object-oriented_programming#encapsulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_programming#encapsulation)

**Question:-** How to implement encapsulation in Javascript without closure can we use something like `Object.freeze` can someone explain with an example

Thank You.

Comment: The article you linked is explaining encapsulation in OOP in general. They explain how to implement encapsulation using JavaScript  in the [next chapter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Classes_in_JavaScript#encapsulation).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP cannot find the required information from a linked documentation, because the information is in the next chapter of the linked documentation.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean if I put _ before a property name it would become
> private

No. `_` before a field name is used to convey to the reader that these field(s) are *meant* to be private; technically they are not private. Other code can access them and mutate them.

Fields that are truly private were recently [introduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) in the Javascript language.

Before the above mentioned feature was introduced, Javascript devs used different techniques to implement private fields - using closures was one of them.